# Serilog loggs only first log to cloudwatch. Need to log all logs

Tags: logging, serilog, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights, .net-core-logging

```
using Amazon.CloudWatchLogs;
using Serilog.Sinks.AwsCloudWatch;

internal class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .WriteTo.AmazonCloudWatch(
            logGroup: LogGroup,
            logStreamPrefix: DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff"),
            cloudWatchClient: client)
            .WriteTo.Console()
            .CreateLogger();
            Log.Information("Application Started");  /*only logs this one*/ 
            Log.Information("Application Started1");
            Log.Information("Application Started2");
            Log.Information("Application Started3");
            Log.Information("Application Started4");
    
        var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureServices((_, services) =>
                .AddSingleton<Serilog.ILogger>(Log.Logger)
             ).UseSerilog()
            .Build();

        var getDDD = ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance\<GetDDD\>(host.Services);
        await getDDD.LoadDDD();   
    }
}
```

I have created a logger using serilog and trying to add it to AWS cloudwatch. But only 1st log get added and rest get skipped. I want to all logs to cloudwatch